# Is it possible for an iPad to get a virus?

Tags: ipad, virus

I was using Safari on my iPad and suddenly a pop up message saying "your device has a virus" appeared. I just clicked okay because that was the only option and then it redirected me to youradexchange.com. Is it possible for my iPad to get a virus?

I'm using iPad mini Retina with iOS 7 and it is not jailbroken.

Comment: The pop-up was almost certainly 'adware' designed to get you to click through to the advertiser's site, in the hope you would buy one of their products.. or at worst [but only if you were running unprotected Windows], to actually give you a virus. The chances of that affecting your iPad are extremely low.

Comment: You can get leading into a sight which may give your device problems, maybe safari will freeze for a certain time to there may be lagging but I don't think it will result in something as major as a virus. But if it does freeze and/or cause other small issues, then try to turn the device off and then on ;) the problem starter might be junk mail or faulty emails.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get malware on an iPad if you install apps from untrusted sources (Anything outside of the App Store).

However, you cannot get a virus from simply going to a website, as the process of installing an app from a third-party requires your interaction and can't be done in the background.

Comment: & how would you install an app from outside… ahh, jailbreak… well, you get what you pay for, I guess

Comment: @Tetsujin Apps can be distributed and installed outside of the App Store without a jailbreak using iTunes manifests.

Comment: True, but unlikely, based on the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the webiste you visited show you a popup and after that redirects you to the link you've given.

Normally it's really hard to get malware on your ipad because every app in the appstore is checked on quality and safety before it will be available.

I think it's not possible to install an app from outside the appstore because those kind of apps made use of a bug in the timezone (or something related to it).

Answer (score -1):

There are many alternative stores for ios and they can contain some viruses
But the chance that you get caught by a virus is low.